Java Spring Boot GraphQL WebSocket closes immediately after opening
I am trying to set up a WebSocket handler for my Java 21 Spring Boot 3.2 application. It is an MVC application and the WebSocket must handle the sub-protocol graphql-ws.
I am using Postman to connect to the WebSocket, but when I try to connect, the connection is immediately closed.
Opened message in Postman:
Connected to ws://localhost:8080/ws

Handshake Details
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/ws
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 101 
Request Headers
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: mzmZ6oZ2ElvK0A7Sz9Fs0g==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: graphql-ws
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: localhost:8080

Response Headers
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: WHyBhldM6qYKH+Zu0qZlcrfIujY=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: graphql-ws
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits=15
Date: Thu, 09 May 2024 18:13:59 GMT

Closed message in Postman:
Disconnected from ws://localhost:8080/ws
12:13:59
4400 Error: Invalid message

Here is my Config class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    private final MyWebSocketHandler myWebSocketHandler;

    public WebsocketConfig(MyWebSocketHandler myWebSocketHandler) {
        this.myWebSocketHandler = myWebSocketHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(myWebSocketHandler, "/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

}

My Handler class:
@Controller
public class MyWebSocketHandler extends GraphQlWebSocketHandler {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyWebSocketHandler.class);

    public MyWebSocketHandler(@Qualifier("mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter") HttpMessageConverter<?> converter,
                              WebGraphQlHandler graphQlHandler) {
        super(graphQlHandler, converter, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(@NonNull WebSocketSession session) {
        logger.info("Handle after connection established for session {}", session.getId());
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(@NonNull WebSocketSession session, @NonNull WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Handle message for session {}: {}", session.getId(), message.getPayload());
        super.handleMessage(session, message);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(@NonNull WebSocketSession session, @NonNull Throwable exception) {
        logger.info("Handle transport error for session {}: {}",session.getId(), exception.getMessage());
        super.handleTransportError(session, exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(@NonNull WebSocketSession session, @NonNull CloseStatus closeStatus) {
        logger.info("Handle after connection closed for session {}: {}:{}", session.getId(), closeStatus.getCode(), closeStatus.getReason());
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, closeStatus);
    }

}

I have this set in my application.yaml:
spring:
  graphql:
    websocket:
      path: /ws

I get these two logs from the Handler class:
2024-05-09T12:37:59.034Z  INFO  c.m.c.MyWebSocketHandler - Handle after connection established for session 846edb0f-7b5d-b19e-e652-1417884e0d52
2024-05-09T12:37:59.034Z  INFO  c.m.c.MyWebSocketHandler - Handle after connection closed for session 846edb0f-7b5d-b19e-e652-1417884e0d52: 4400:Invalid message

My dependencies I have:
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-graphql:3.2.0"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.0"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:3.2.0"

In Postman I am trying with both the "Connect" and sending a "connection_init" message:
{
    "type": "connection_init",
    "payload": {
        "token": "{{jwt}}"
    }
}

I am running the app locally and I have tried the following:
localhost:8080/ws
ws://localhost:8080/ws

Why is my WebSocket closing immediately? Why is the "message" invalid?
Also, the application uses MVC (for other APIs), so no WebFlux.
Thanks
Edit:
I have found that the connection works if I remove the Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: graphql-ws from my headers...but I need to support that sub-protocol...
Without the sub-protocol, I get this error when I try to send my GraphQL Subscription message:
1011 Server Error: Internal server error while operating.

Here is my Subscription message:
{
   "id": "{myId}",
   "type": "start",
   "payload": {
      "query": "{my graphql query}"
   }
}


I don't think your application needs the MyWebSocketHandler nor the WebsocketConfig at all, this should be all done for you.
I think the connection is rejected because the now deprecated "graphql-ws" sub-protocol is not supported in Spring for GraphQL; only the "graphql-transport-ws" protocol is implemented.
